# Strange behavior of std::string with unicode

Tags: c++, ubuntu, unicode, g++, clang

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string eps("ε");

int main()
{
    std::cout << eps << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Somehow it compiles with g++ and clang on Ubuntu, and even prints out right character `ε`.
Also I have almost same piece of code which happily reads `ε` with `cin` into `std::string`.
By the way, `eps.size()` is 2.

My question is - how that works? How can we insert unicode character into `std::string`?
My guess is that operating system handles all this work with unicode, but I'm not sure.

**EDIT**

As with output, I understood that it is terminal who is responsible for showing me right character (ε in this case).

But with input: cin reads symbols to `' '` or any other space character (and as I understand byte by byte). So, if I take `Ƞ`, which second byte is 32 `' '` it will read only first byte, and then stop. But it reads `Ƞ`. How?

Comment: Maybe the editor you're using saves the file with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how `std::cout` outputs one symbol instead of two - first and second byte of ε. As far as I know `std::cout` works with one-byte encodings.

Comment: std::cout just sends a stream to the terminal.  If your terminal handles UTF-8, this should work fine.

Comment: @SHR You're talking about Windows-specific Unicode quirks, but the question is clearly tagged Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe you are compiling with the wrong charset. Look up the g++ docs for the -finput-charset option so that you have something like:

-finput-charset=UTF-16

when you make your project.

Comment: @MrEricSir Actually, it seems that everything in Ubuntu supports UTF-8, so ε is being output everywhere. It seems that you are right. But there is also question with input. `cin` reads string to space character. But even if I try to read unicode character, and it's second byte is 32 (`' '`), it reads second perfectly. How?

Comment: @SHR I'm not aware of any platform where wstrings can store UTF-8.  On Windows a wstring represents UTF-16, on Linux it's UTF-32.

Comment: @SHR What does *his string is not UNICODE but UTF-8* mean? Please stop spreading nonsense. Guess what, I'm typing in *UNICODE* right now. The explanations given by others above are correct. His editor saved the file in utf-8 and his terminal knows how to handle utf-8, so everything worked. This has nothing to do with `wstring`, which, by the way, doesn't know how to handle all of Unicode's complexities either.

Comment: Recommending to read http://utf8everywhere.org for clarification on encodings and usage of std::string.

Comment: When characters are encoded as UTF-8, they are not simply stored as their Unicode code point. For example, `Ƞ` is not stored as the hexadecimal bytes 02 20. Instead, they are encoded in a special UTF-8 format, which for `Ƞ` is C8 A0.

Comment: The UTF-8 encoding was thoughtfully designed to be backwards compatible with 7-bit ASCII, and works with applications that treat C-style strings as streams of single-byte characters with a trailing null byte. No character other than the null character has a null byte anywhere in its encoding. Also, no UTF-8 character will contain a 7-bit ASCII character in its encoding unless it is that ASCII character. All non-ASCII Unicode characters are encoded only with bytes that are 0x80 and above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely reason is that everything is getting encoded in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), as it does on my system:

```
$ xxd test.cpp
...
0000020: 2065 7073 2822 ceb5 2229 3b0a 0a69 6e74   eps("..");..int
                        ^^^^ ε in UTF-8                 ^^ TWO bytes!
...
$ g++ -o test.out test.cpp
$ ./test.out 
ε
$ ./test.out | xxd
0000000: ceb5 0a
         ^^^^
```